# How to put background image below another one, using sections?

Tags: html, css

maybe there are similar questions but none of them helped me so:
I have a fixed header :

```
header {
position: fixed;
display: flex;
top: 0;
background: rgba(212, 161, 51, 0.8);
height : 8vh;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-around;
z-index: 999;}
```

And I have got two sections:

```
.s1 {
background-image: url(../img.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;}

.s2 {
    background-image: url(../img2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 100vh;
    
}
```

I am using a spacer to move the content which will be displayed below the header:

```
.spacer {
width: 100%;
height: 8vh;
}
```

Here is the HTML of the sections:

```
<main>
    <section className = 's1'>
        <div className='spacer'></div>      
    </section>
    <section className='s2'>
        <div className='spacer'></div>
    </section>
</main>
```

The point is - first section takes the whole screen to display an image, second section does the same, but goes below the first section.
I have tried playing a lot with the **background** properties, also with the **positions** and **display** properties, but I can't seem to place the second image below the first one. Best I got is second image on top of the first one. Any thoughts how can I make this happen?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus As I said I played with the background props, with which I meant that I removed and modified them, so let's say I dont use the fixed attachment. What position rather than absolute would you suggest me use for the sections, since removing the background attachment still places the second image over the first one.

Comment: okay, you have your answer ;) great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, you can use css: z-index: 1;

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... are layers to use.

```
.yourClass {
z-index: 5
}
```

Comment: a little step for the mankinda big step for a man. This feels great. i got goose bumps. i start coding since 3 weeks with 35 year.